# On data type for macros in C

Tags: c

Let's say I have a macro so defined:

```
#define BitVal(data,y) ( (data>>y) & 1)      /** Return Data.Y value   **/
```

it simply returns the value of the bit on a given position `y`.

Do I have some restrictions on the data type of the variable `data`? Can it be indifferently `int`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long long` et cetera? if so, are there kinds of control mechanisms in order to do not have never overflow?

Comment: Macros are a simple text replacement. There are no data types involved.

Comment: Macro is a simple textual replacement. The restriction is the same as for the general  `( (data>>y) & 1)`  expression. Perhaps you wanted to ask about it instead?

Comment: so the question should be: which is the data type I can insert in `data` ensuring the correct behavior? the compiler does not give me an error

Comment: You can use the `>>` operator on any *integral* type. If you try with a `double`, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: `long`, `long long` are example were you do not have errors

Comment: I will do some tests and report the results here

Comment: What errors? What results? The comments are clear enough. `data` can be any integral type. `data` and `y` are subject to constraints in the C standard http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your desired behavior when an overflow would happen. If you want to validate the data maybe it's more appropriate to use a function instead of a macro.

Alternatively, would something like this work?

```
#define BitVal(data,y) ((sizeof(data) < y) ? ((data>>y) & 1) : (0)
```

Comment: not testing but just reading it, if the condition is not respected, it will give `0` as output. And the program will think that the value of the bit is `0` in the position `y`. Right?

Comment: `sizeof` is a size in *bytes*.

Comment: `sizeof()` gives a number of bytes, `y` is in bits (and pedantically you'd have to take into account non 8-bit bytes and padding in `y`).

Comment: Actually the behavior of right shift is defined for any `y` (my initial comment was wrong). Yet for negative `data` it would be *implementation*-defined

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear: macros have no bearing on data types. Calling this macro with the variable names "data" and "y" as arguments is exactly like putting "( (data>>y) & 1)" directly in your code. So the answer is, no, there are no data type restrictions because this is a macro, nor could there be.

(If you pass in expressions instead of variable names, there's another problem that isn't part of your question, but it still has nothing to do with data types.)